# How to parse diffgram anytype response from .net webservice

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following response from a .net webservice which is of anytype format.I need to parse this format and read the data value like RemMessage and INVM_ID provided in the format.I am not able to parse this format and get appropriate value.The java code is ..

```
public class WebService {

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);
        androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
        androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("");
        // Property which holds input parameters
        PropertyInfo sayHelloPI = new PropertyInfo();
        // Set Name
        sayHelloPI.setName("UserId");
        // Set Value
        sayHelloPI.setValue("41");
        // Set dataType
        sayHelloPI.setType(String.class);
        // Add the property to request object
       request.addProperty(sayHelloPI);
        //Set envelope as dotNet
       envelope.dotNet = true;
       envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
       try {
            List<GetReminder> reminders = new ArrayList<>();
            androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            // Get the response
            String response=androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
            Log.d("Result --- ", response.toString() );
            SoapObject obj=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
            System.out.println("obj---->" + obj.toString());
         } catch (SocketException e) {
            Log.e("Error :" ,"Error " +e.getMessage());
            //Print error
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Assign error message to resTxt
            resTxt = "Error occured";
        }
        catch (XmlPullParserException e1)
        {
            String resp=androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
            e1.printStackTrace();
            resTxt = "Error occured";
        }
        //Return resTxt to calling object
        return resTxt;
    }
}
```

This is returning me a response like below ,i need to read the data of these params RemMessage ,InvM_Id and i have GetReminder class like

```
public class GetReminder implements Serializable {
    private String RemMessage;
    private int InvM_Id;
    private int DocType;
    private int PrmR_TypeId;
    private int PrmR_Id;

    public String getRemMessage() {
        return RemMessage;
    }

    public void setRemMessage(String remMessage) {
        RemMessage = remMessage;
    }

    public int getInvM_Id() {
        return InvM_Id;
    }

    public void setInvM_Id(int invM_Id) {
        InvM_Id = invM_Id;
    }

    public int getPrmR_TypeId() {
        return PrmR_TypeId;
    }

    public void setPrmR_TypeId(int prmR_TypeId) {
        PrmR_TypeId = prmR_TypeId;
    }

    public int getDocType() {
        return DocType;
    }

    public void setDocType(int docType) {
        DocType = docType;
    }

    public int getPrmR_Id() {
        return PrmR_Id;
    }

    public void setPrmR_Id(int prmR_Id) {
        PrmR_Id = prmR_Id;
    }

}
```

Response format

```
 anyType {
    schema = anyType {
        element = anyType {
            complexType = anyType {
                choice = anyType {
                    element = anyType {
                        complexType = anyType {
                            sequence = anyType {
                                element = anyType {

                                };
                                element = anyType {

                                };
                                element = anyType {

                                };
                                element = anyType {

                                };
                                element = anyType {

                                };
                            };
                        };
                    };
                };
            };
        };
    };
    diffgram = anyType {
        NewDataSet = anyType {
            Table = anyType {
                RemMessage = ExeedDiscountLimitonInvoicedatedon05 / 03 / 2015forCSHAH,
                from3 - LokhandwalaShowroom;
                InvM_Id = 77693;
                DocType = 3;
                PrmR_TypeId = 3;
                PrmR_Id = 1820;
            };
        };
    };
    }
```

This is just a single message format (RemMessage) ,i will be getting multiple entries of RemMessage.

Comment: this may help [Android and .NET Webservice - parsing the returned xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462399/android-and-net-webservice-parsing-the-returned-xml)

Comment: @maveň i had a look at this before posting but this different has per my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included XML representation of soap response in this post: [Parsing Complex Soap Response with diffgram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046128/parsing-complex-soap-response-with-diffgram/30059614#30059614). And there we may see, that first element ("schema = anyType {...") is only a definition of type "NewDataSet". So You need to parse only second part, that holds data for GetReminder models.
The code is under Your last posting here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30059614/4114960

Answer (score 0):

```
public  ArrayList<Object> deserializeSoap(SoapObject soapObj) {
        if(soapObj!=null){
            if(soapObj.hasProperty("GetReminderResult")){
                SoapObject SoapObj1 = (SoapObject) soapObj.getProperty("GetReminderResult");
            if(soapObj1.hasProperty("schema")){
                SoapObject soapObj2 = (SoapObject) soapObj1.getProperty("schema");
                if(soapObj2.hasProperty("element")){
                    SoapObject SoapObj3 = (SoapObject) soapObj2.getProperty("element");
                    if(SoapObj3.hasProperty("complexType")){
                    SoapObject SoapObj4 = (SoapObject) SoapObj3.getProperty("complexType");
                     if(SoapObj4.hasProperty("choice")){
                          SoapObject SoapObj5 = (SoapObject) SoapObj4.getProperty("choice");
                     if(SoapObj5.hasProperty("element")){
                         SoapObject SoapObj6 = (SoapObject) SoapObj5.getProperty("element");
                         if(SoapObj6.hasProperty("sequence")){
                              SoapObject SoapObj7 = (SoapObject) SoapObj6.getProperty("sequence");
                              if(SoapObj7.hasProperty("element"))
                              {
                                  getListFromSoapObj(SoapObj7)
                                  }
                             }
                         }
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
           }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static ArrayList<Object> getListFromSoapObj(SoapObject soapObj) {
        ArrayList<Object> memberObjList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < soapObj.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
            Object memberObj = new Object();
            SoapObject soapObjectInner = (SoapObject) soapObj.getProperty(i);
            if (soapObjectInner.hasProperty("RemMessage")) {
                memberObj.setImageId(soapObjectInner
                        .getPropertyAsString("RemMessage"));
            }
            memberObjList.add(memberObj);
        }
        return memberObjList;
        System.out.println("---------------------" + memberObjList.size());
    }
```

Comment: Let me try and i will let you know

Comment: Getting illegal property NewDataSet..,eventhough its present

Comment: any input for illegal property ?